# How to use a Bootstrap 5 class (form-check) with Django 3.2.2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, bootstrap-5, django-model-field

I am learning Django and I want to use the form-check Bootstrap class for a checkbox but it isn't working correctly.

This is the code of my file `vaccines_form.html`:

```
{{ form.vacuna }}
```

This code of my file `forms.py` works fine:

```
widgets = {
    'vacuna': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
}
```

[image: Vaccines]

But this doesn't work well:

```
widgets = {
    'vacuna': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}),
}
```

[image: Vaccines]

I am using Django 3.2.2 with Bootstrap v5.0.0 but I am not sure if Bootstrap 5 is compatible with Django 3.2.2. Maybe I don't have to use Bootstrap classes in `forms.py` and use only in `vaccines_form.html`.

Answer (score 1):

save time and try django crispy forms

Comment: You won't have much success just a adding classes to the Django forms as the HTML layout is different as well as the CSS classes. As Ahmed said, django-crispy-forms is a solution here and there is a new Bootstrap 5 template pack. (Disclaimer, I'm the main contributor to this package)